# Health check for GCP Load balancer (from terraform)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create GCP infrastructure, to be more precise, load balancer using module "gce-lb-http" for Terraform. Below is the error:

```
╷
│ Error: Error creating HealthCheck: googleapi: Error 403: Required 
'compute.healthChecks.create' permission for 'projects/gcptf- 
320808/global/healthChecks/tf-createdlb-hc-default', forbidden 
│  
│   with module.gce-lb-http.google_compute_health_check.default["default"],
│   on .terraform/modules/gce-lb-http/main.tf line 203, in resource 
"google_compute_health_check" "default":
│  203: resource "google_compute_health_check" "default" {
```

So I have no idea why health check creating is forbidden? How can I allow the creation of this?

Comment: Your user (or Service Account) who is triggering Terraform needs this permission in order to be able to create HealthChecks 'compute.healthChecks.create'

Comment: Good point @Caiot, if SA has correct permissions, check project id define in file, people make the common mistake of using project name instead of project ID. Also please hide your project ID for your own security on Stackoverflow.

Comment: i am using default SA with granted load balancing admin role( that contain health check creating permission). Project id that u can see in question line are correct

Answer (score 1):

Your user (or Service Account) which is triggerred by Terraform needs this permission in order to be able to create HealthChecks 'compute.healthChecks.create'. You

If service account has correct permissions, check project id defined in a config file, it's common mistake using project name instead of project ID, or just misspelling the ID itself.

Have a look at the documentation descibing how to [add roles to a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) and how to [make custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) in case you need some specific permissions.

You may also find [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644265/terraform-gcp-project-creation) useful.